# Android push notification vs firebase push notification

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I found a link about android push notification - https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification, can I know the difference between the android push notification (based on the link) and firebase push notification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Android <strike>Push</strike> Notification:

> A [Notification](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications) is a message that Android displays outside your
> app's UI to provide the user with reminders, communication from other
> people, or other timely information from your app. Users can tap the
> notification to open your app or take an action directly from the
> notification.

### Firebase Notification:

> Using [FCM,](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) you can notify a client app that a new email or other
> data is available to sync. You can send notification messages to drive
> user re-engagement and retention.

For more, you can visit the above links.

Comment: Great answer Pratik! FCM is indeed the delivery mechanism for messages, while Android Notifications are how then display them in the notification center.

Comment: @PratikButani Indeed, great answer Pratik.